# Laravel - option value form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Welcome ! I have a problem . I try to connect via relations two models. If i create note it belongs to only one user. Problem is that in form options don't know why it doesn't display me users from database.

NotesController :

```
public function create()

{
    $data['pilots'] = Pilot::all();
    return view('uwagi.create',$data);

}
```

Create blade:

```
<label>Pilot</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="pilot" name="pilots[]">
    @foreach($pilots as $pilot)
      <option value="{!! $pilot->id !!}"
        {!! $pilot->name !!}
      </option>


    @endforeach
  </select>
```

Regards and thank u for help

Comment: Try Pilot::with('users')->get() in create method. Then in form call $pilot->user->name

Comment: ok problem was that i not finished option value with " >"

Answer (score 1):

You are sending variable named $data but your foreach loop doesnot contain data variable, why?

```
public function create()

{
    $pilots = Pilot::all();
    return view('uwagi.create',$pilots);

}
```

Hope it's helps you.

Answer (score 0):

pls modify your controller like this

```
public function create()
{
$pilots = Pilot::all();
return view('uwagi.create', compact('pilots'));
}
```